# Showing that $\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac1{n(\log n)(\log\log n)}$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I know that the series diverge, I'm just having hard time showing it.

$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac1{n(\log n)(\log\log n)}$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please learn how to type formulas on the site.

Answer (score 10):

The [Cauchy Condensation Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) will do it.

If you have not seen it, here is what it says. Suppose that $f(n)$ is positive nonincreasing. Then $\sum_{a}^\infty f(n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_a^\infty 2^nf(2^n)$ converges.

In our case, we have $f(n)=\frac{1}{n\log n\log\log n}$. Thus $2^n f(2^n)=\frac{1}{(n\log 2)(\log n+\log\log 2)}$. The divergence of $\sum 2^n f(2^n)$ now follows from the possibly familiar fact that $\sum_2^\infty \frac{1}{n\log n}$ diverges. If that fact is not familiar, we can use Cauchy Condensation again.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that the divergence of $\sum \frac{1}{(n\log 2)(\log n+\log\log 2)}$ follows from the divergence of $\sum\frac{1}{n\log n}$ because $ \frac{1}{(n\log 2)(\log n+\log\log 2)} \geq \frac{1}{(n\log2)(2\log n)} = \frac{1}{(2\log 2)(n\log n)} $?

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Use the integral test. There’s a nice $u$-substitution available to handle the integral.

Comment: thak you, dont know why i didn't try it before...

Comment: @matan: You’re welcome.

Answer (score -2):

Hint:  Use the comparison test with 1/log(n)

Comment: This is incorrect. If $ \sum \frac{1}{\log n} $ converged, then this sum would converge. However, that sum diverges so it says nothing about the convergence of this sum.